# get_footer not showing updated content in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, footer

I have multiple footers in layouts , I am trying to show the footer on blog single page like this:

In `single.php`

```
    <?php get_footer('Footer 3');?>
```

Layouts:

[image]

However this only shows the default "Footer 3" from the template file (without any updates that were made in the admin section).

Comment: Create template footer-3.php  and access your footer   <?php get_footer('3');?> try this and let me know

Comment: @HarshKhare thanks for the reply, but it is only showing the template version but not the updated one which is saved through visual editor

Comment: You might have a cache issue. Do use any caching plugins?

Comment: @muka.gergely thanks!! it was cache issues , had a caching plugin running

Comment: Happy to help :)